# How to select an remembered item in the text box with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java

How to select an remembered item in the text box with Selenium webdriver?

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i=0; i<strs.length; i++){
            char[] arr = strs[i].toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            String t = String.valueOf(arr);
            if(map.get(t) == null){
                ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                l.add(i);
                map.put(t, l);
            }else{
                map.get(t).add(i);
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit wait for the element to become visible/clickable?

Comment: You are missing information. What line of your code is that error in? Please have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Please try below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
driver.findElement(By.id("PRODUCT_quickAddInput")).sendKeys(“00006692”);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='div_0']"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
element.click();
```